# Поиск ключевых слов по регулярному выражению

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Нужно найти все слова, перед и после которых может идти любой `non-word character`

Например в этой строке все слова будут верны: `;false;true;else; true else false`

А тут нет: `trueelsefalse truefalse sfalse`

Моё регулярное выражение `\W(true|else|false)\W`

Но почему-то у меня ничего не работает. Вот [регулярка](https://regex101.com/r/W6RPxk/3/)

Comment: Так нужны любые слова, или true/else/false?

Comment: Может, [`\b(true|else|false)\b`](https://regex101.com/r/W6RPxk/4)?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Спасибо огромное, то что нужно!